# get records that have only 1 record per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have attendance db data as follows (sql server)

```
empid       date          type
1           01-Jan         In
1           01-Jan         Out
2           01-Jan         In
3           01-Jan         In
3           01-Jan         Out
```

How can we get records that have only 1 record per date per employee (in above case empid 2 for 01-jan)?

The query should simply list all records of employees that have only single type for a day.

**EDIT**

The result set should be a bit more specific: show all employee who only have "In" for a date but no "Out"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't what you tried work? Did you get an error, unexpected results? If you haven't tried, why not? When you searched for a solution what didn't you understand about the articles/documentation/examples you read?

Comment: @Larnu you're right.....

Comment: @Larnu i thought of trying group by and having but that did not help in identifying the requirement that "show records in which date that an employee only checked out and not In"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a
where not exists (select 1 from tablename b where a.empid=b.empid and  a.date=b.date and type='Out')
```

OR

```
select empid, date,count(distinct type)
from tablename
group by empid,date
having count(distinct type)=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Having`

```
select empid, date, count(*)
from Mytable
group by empid, date
having count(*) = 1
```

You can use this to get the full line:

```
select t1.*
from MyTable t1
inner join 
(
    select empid, date, count(*)
    from Mytable
    group by empid, date
    having count(*) = 1
) t2
on t1.empid = t2.empid
and t1.date = t2.date
```

Comment: Keep in mind the second query can and will select "duplicated" records on the empid and date column

Comment: thank you for the answer , but can it handle the case that show only the records which have an Out but no In

Answer (score 3):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by empid, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

You can also use aggregation:

```
select empid, date, max(type) as type
from t
group by empid, date
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is Very Simple, You can use 'DISTINCT' function.
Query Should be as,

```
SELECT DISTINCT empid FROM attendance
```

This will return only 1 record per date per employee.

For Your Reference, Check it out- https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/distinct.php

Comment: Maybe you should read about the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) option which are available to use on this website as you are new here.

Comment: But this answer is wrong as it also will select empid which has more then one record..

Comment: Your answer will return all employees, while OP is looking for a solution that will only return emp#2.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if we have ID with 1 IN OR 1 OUT as well

```
Declare @t table (empid int,date varchar(50),types varchar(50))

insert into @t values (1,'01-Jan','IN')
insert into @t values (1,'01-Jan','OUT')
insert into @t values (2,'01-Jan','IN')
insert into @t values (3,'01-Jan','OUT')
insert into @t values (4,'01-Jan','OUT')

select * from @t a
where not exists (select 1 from @t b where a.empid=b.empid and a.types!=b.types)
```